# Sum variables based on position size to create top values by group in R

Tags: r, data.table, dplyr

I am trying to figure out the best way to sum columns by group and totals in a cumulative sort of way. What I would like to do is grab the top value by `group.1` and `group.2` as a new variable `total_top_1`. After I get this value, I would like to create a second variable, `total_top_2` and add it to the first value. Starting with this data.

```
    df <- data.frame(stringsAsFactors=FALSE,
         group.1 = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A",
                     "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B",
                     "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B"),
         group.2 = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L,
                     1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L,
                     2L),
           value = c(56L, 74L, 39L, 86L, 7L, 100L, 18L, 43L, 68L, 32L, 4L, 17L,
                     18L, 24L, 94L, 11L, 67L, 87L, 96L, 93L, 31L, 29L, 31L,
                     25L, 64L, 23L, 44L, 92L, 36L, 93L)
)
```

I would like the end result to look like this.

```
df_output <- data.frame(stringsAsFactors=FALSE,
  group.1 = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A",
               "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B",
               "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B"),
  group.2 = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L,
               1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L),
  value = c(56L, 74L, 39L, 86L, 7L, 100L, 18L, 43L, 68L, 32L, 4L, 17L,
               18L, 24L, 94L, 11L, 67L, 87L, 96L, 93L, 31L, 29L, 31L, 25L,
               64L, 23L, 44L, 92L, 36L, 93L),
  total_top_1 = c(100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 32L,
                   32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 96L, 96L, 96L, 96L, 96L, 96L, 96L, 96L,
                   96L, 93L, 93L, 93L, 93L, 93L, 93L, 93L),
  total_top_2 = c(186L, 186L, 186L, 186L, 186L, 186L, 186L, 186L, 186L, 56L,
                   56L, 56L, 56L, 56L, 190L, 190L, 190L, 190L, 190L, 190L,
                   190L, 190L, 190L, 185L, 185L, 185L, 185L, 185L, 185L, 185L)
```

)

Ideally, I want to be able to do this for a number of variables that I specify. So, it could be that I need to create `total_top_1` to `total_top_5`.

To get the total for the top 1 and 2 I could do something like this:

```
df %>% 
  arrange(group.1, group.2, desc(value)) %>% 
  group_by(group.1, group.2) %>% 
  top_n(
    n = 2, wt = value
  ) %>% 
  mutate(
    total_top_1 = value,
    total_top_2 = sum(value)
 )
```

However, if I want to get the top 3 I need to repeat this step, edit `top_n` and now `sum` is calculating `total_top_3` where what I really want is `total_top_1`, `total_top_2`, and `total_top_3`. I assume there is a much better way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you want .

```
library(reshape2)
df=df%>%group_by(group.1,group.2)%>%dplyr:: mutate(top_n=rank(-value,ties.method = "first"))
df$Group=paste(df$group.1,df$group.2)
df1=as.data.frame((acast(df, Group~top_n, value.var="value")))
df1[is.na(df1)]=0
df1=as.data.frame(t(apply(df1, 1, cumsum)))
names(df1)=paste("total_top_", colnames(df1))
df1$Group=rownames(df1)
df=merge(df,df1,by.x='Group',by.y='Group',all.x=T)
```

and here is the out put :

```
> df
   Group group.1 group.2 value top_n total_top_ 1 total_top_ 2 total_top_ 3 total_top_ 4 total_top_ 5 total_top_ 6 total_top_ 7 total_top_ 8 total_top_ 9
1    A 1       A       1    56     5          100          186          260          328          384          427          466          484          491
2    A 1       A       1    74     3          100          186          260          328          384          427          466          484          491
3    A 1       A       1    39     7          100          186          260          328          384          427          466          484          491
4    A 1       A       1    86     2          100          186          260          328          384          427          466          484          491
5    A 1       A       1     7     9          100          186          260          328          384          427          466          484          491
6    A 1       A       1   100     1          100          186          260          328          384          427          466          484          491
7    A 1       A       1    18     8          100          186          260          328          384          427          466          484          491
8    A 1       A       1    43     6          100          186          260          328          384          427          466          484          491
9    A 1       A       1    68     4          100          186          260          328          384          427          466          484          491
10   A 2       A       2    32     1           32           56           74           91           95           95           95           95           95
11   A 2       A       2     4     5           32           56           74           91           95           95           95           95           95
12   A 2       A       2    17     4           32           56           74           91           95           95           95           95           95
13   A 2       A       2    18     3           32           56           74           91           95           95           95           95           95
14   A 2       A       2    24     2           32           56           74           91           95           95           95           95           95
15   B 1       B       1    94     2           96          190          283          370          437          468          499          528          539
16   B 1       B       1    11     9           96          190          283          370          437          468          499          528          539
17   B 1       B       1    67     5           96          190          283          370          437          468          499          528          539
18   B 1       B       1    87     4           96          190          283          370          437          468          499          528          539
19   B 1       B       1    96     1           96          190          283          370          437          468          499          528          539
20   B 1       B       1    93     3           96          190          283          370          437          468          499          528          539
21   B 1       B       1    31     6           96          190          283          370          437          468          499          528          539
22   B 1       B       1    29     8           96          190          283          370          437          468          499          528          539
23   B 1       B       1    31     7           96          190          283          370          437          468          499          528          539
24   B 2       B       2    25     6           93          185          249          293          329          354          377          377          377
25   B 2       B       2    64     3           93          185          249          293          329          354          377          377          377
26   B 2       B       2    23     7           93          185          249          293          329          354          377          377          377
27   B 2       B       2    44     4           93          185          249          293          329          354          377          377          377
28   B 2       B       2    92     2           93          185          249          293          329          354          377          377          377
29   B 2       B       2    36     5           93          185          249          293          329          354          377          377          377
30   B 2       B       2    93     1           93          185          249          293          329          354          377          377          377
```